# I am getting urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway

Tags: python, json, url

/* Iam getting urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway.*/

```
import urllib2
import json

# locu_api = 'd1dab0b393b10f56532cacf6835d2619973f5f46' 
url = 'http://cricapi.com/api/cricketNews'
/*The above url is used from cricapi.com*/
str = ""

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)
i = 0
titles = {}

for item in data['data']:
    if item:
        titles[i] = item['title']
        i+=1
print titles
/*printing all the content fetched from cricapi*/
if not str:
    print "Hello"
```

After building the above code, 
I am getting following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/karthi/Desktop/proj/cric.py", line 51, in <module>
  json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
  urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
```

Before a week. I was able to get the result. But now I am getting the error.

Can anybody explain please about the hinderance I am getting and also please provide a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Karthi, the problem you state is common for a lot of API providers. What happens is if the server load exceeds capacity for that instant, you may get a 502 from the reverse proxy and thus experience an error situation.

The recommended way to get around this is to have a retry count. For example

```
function fetchdata(url) {
  try { 
    // hit the URL and fetch data
  } catch() {
    // retry in case of an error
    return fetchdata(url); 
  }
}
```

Another method if you're using a callback-supporting language is to retry a given number of times and then invoke the callback

```
function fetchdata(url, callback) {
  try { 
    // hit the URL and fetch data
    // success!
    callback(returndata);
  } catch() {
    // retry in case of an error
    if(exceeded retry count) callback(error); 
else 
    fetchdata(url, callback); 
  }
}
```

Note: this is sample pseudocode not proper usable code so please treat it as such

Naturally the only long term fix is to get in touch with the API provider and request them to help figure out what's wrong. Most API providers tend to be fairly anal about quality of service and if they see someone facing issues are likely to provide assistance quickly.